# Error con f=lambda x usando input en sympy y scipy

Tags: python, lambda, scipy, sympy, calculo

Estoy intentando hacer un código que le pida al usuario tanto las variables a usar como la función para una integral, hasta aquí todo correcto, pero al pedir que las evalúe como una integral definida (con números que igual da el usuario con input) me marca el siguiente error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Franc\OneDrive - Instituto Tecnologico y de Estudios Superiores de Monterrey\1er Semestre\Pensamiento computacional para ingeniería\Proyecto\Función integral.py", line 53, in <module>
    integrar()
  File "C:\Users\Franc\OneDrive - Instituto Tecnologico y de Estudios Superiores de Monterrey\1er Semestre\Pensamiento computacional para ingeniería\Proyecto\Función integral.py", line 33, in integrar
    integral=parse_expr(integral)
  File "C:\Users\Franc\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\sympy\parsing\sympy_parser.py", line 1003, in parse_expr
    code = stringify_expr(s, local_dict, global_dict, transformations)
  File "C:\Users\Franc\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\sympy\parsing\sympy_parser.py", line 886, in stringify_expr
    input_code = StringIO(s.strip())
AttributeError: 'Mul' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

Este es mi código:

```
import sympy
from sympy import *
from sympy import Symbol
from sympy import sympify
from sympy import integrate
from scipy.integrate import quad
from scipy.misc import derivative

#Función que le pide al usuario una función en términos de x para después integrarla e imprimir el resultado.
#Como extra le pregunta si quiere evaluar esa integral en un intervalo, es decir una integral definida.
def integrar():
    x=(input(("Dame tu variable: ")))
    while True:
        if x.isalpha()==True:
            x=Symbol(x)
            expr=parse_expr(input("Dame tu función (Recuerda usar bien los paréntesis y que los exponentes se escriben con ** \n Ejemplo: 2*x**3 se lee: Dos equis al cubo): "))
            integral=(integrate(expr))
            print()
            print("La integral de ", expr, "es \n", integral, "\n")
            print("¿Quieres definir la integral? \n 1:Sí \n 2:No \n")
            evaluar=(input())
            print()
            if evaluar=="1":
                y,z,w=sympy.symbols("y z w")
                z=(input("Dame el número mayor (el valor que le darás a x o a tu variable): "))
                while z.isalpha()==True:
                    z=(input("Opción no válida, dame un número (el valor que le darás a x o a tu variable): "))
                w=(input("Dame el número menor de la integral definida (el valor que le darás a x o a tu variable): "))
                while w.isalpha()==True:
                    w=(input("Opción no válida, dame un número (el valor que le darás a x o a tu variable): "))
                z=int(z)
                w=int(w)
                integral=parse_expr(integral)
                f=lambda x:integral
                z=parse_expr(z)
                w=parse_expr(w)
                print(quad(f,w,z))
                print()
                print("Gracias por usar calculando, vuelva pronto")
                print()
                break
            elif evaluar=="2":
                print("Gracias por usar calculando, vuelva pronto")
                print()
                break
            else:
                print("Opción no válida inténtalo otra vez")
                print()
                break
        else:
            x=(input(("No válido, dame una letra como variable: ")))
   
integrar()
```

Espero me haya dado a entender, todo marcha bien hasta intentar hacer la integral ya dada como una definida, no sé usar muy bien sympy ni scipy y supongo debe haber una función sencilla para ocrregir esto, espero me puedan ayudar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No se recomienda hacer

```
from simpy import *
```

si no importar cada función explicitamente.

Segundo, `lambda` no funciona con expresiones sympy, tienes que usar `lambdify`

Finalmente, los símbolos hay que construirlos con strings, no con valores númericos. Entonces, en lugar de

```
z=int(z)
w=int(w)
...
z=parse_expr(z)
w=parse_expr(w)
```

simplemente dices

```
z=parse_expr(z)
w=parse_expr(w)
```

Reparsear la integral, como aqui:

```
integral=parse_expr(integral)
```

no tiene sentido, ya que la `integral` ya es una expresión.

Con todo, queda asi:

```
from sympy import Symbol, parse_expr, lambdify
from sympy import sympify
from sympy import integrate
import sympy.geometry.util
from scipy.integrate import quad
from scipy.misc import derivative

#Función que le pide al usuario una función en términos de x para después integrarla e imprimir el resultado.
#Como extra le pregunta si quiere evaluar esa integral en un intervalo, es decir una integral definida.
def integrar():
    x=(input(("Dame tu variable: ")))
    while True:
        if x.isalpha()==True:
            x=Symbol(x)
            expr=parse_expr(input("Dame tu función (Recuerda usar bien los paréntesis y que los exponentes se escriben con ** \n Ejemplo: 2*x**3 se lee: Dos equis al cubo): "))
            integral=(integrate(expr))
            print()
            print("La integral de ", expr, "es \n", integral, "\n")
            print("¿Quieres definir la integral? \n 1:Sí \n 2:No \n")
            evaluar=(input())
            print()
            if evaluar=="1":
                y,z,w=sympy.symbols("y z w")
                z=(input("Dame el número mayor (el valor que le darás a x o a tu variable): "))
                while z.isalpha()==True:
                    z=(input("Opción no válida, dame un número (el valor que le darás a x o a tu variable): "))
                w=(input("Dame el número menor de la integral definida (el valor que le darás a x o a tu variable): "))
                while w.isalpha()==True:
                    w=(input("Opción no válida, dame un número (el valor que le darás a x o a tu variable): "))
                #z=int(z)
                #w=int(w)
                #1integral=parse_expr(integral)
                f=lambdify(x, integral, "numpy")
                z=parse_expr(z)
                w=parse_expr(w)
                print(quad(f,w,z))
                print()
                print("Gracias por usar calculando, vuelva pronto")
                print()
                break
            elif evaluar=="2":
                print("Gracias por usar calculando, vuelva pronto")
                print()
                break
            else:
                print("Opción no válida inténtalo otra vez")
                print()
                break
        else:
            x=(input(("No válido, dame una letra como variable: ")))

integrar()
```

**Prueba**

Con la expresión `2*x**3` y limites de integración entre 1 y 10, produce

```
Dame tu variable: x
Dame tu función (Recuerda usar bien los paréntesis y que los exponentes se escriben con ** 
 Ejemplo: 2*x**3 se lee: Dos equis al cubo): 2*x**3

La integral de  2*x**3 es 
 x**4/2 

¿Quieres definir la integral? 
 1:Sí 
 2:No 

1

Dame el número mayor (el valor que le darás a x o a tu variable): 10
Dame el número menor de la integral definida (el valor que le darás a x o a tu variable): 1
(9999.900000000001, 1.1102119223949104e-10)

Gracias por usar calculando, vuelva pronto
```

Nota: No puede comprobar el resultado de la integral, pero al menos no se cae.
(No se donde deje mis tablas Larsen y la regla de cálculo).

**Comprobación matemática**

Recurri a este sitio [Integral Calculator](https://www.integral-calculator.com/) para verificar los resultados:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

obteniendo este resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que confirma el resultado obtenido por el código.

Comment: He hecho varios intentos y de hecho en el ejemplo que me pusiste el resultado de la integral definida está mal, que ha pasado?

Comment: @FranciscoGarcíaBarrada. Revise el resultado por un método independiente y me parece que está correcto. Edite mi respuesta con la comprobación. Por favor, revisa.

Comment: @FranciscoGarcíaBarrada. Creo que la función `quad` debería aplicarse sobre la expresión original (`2*x**3`), no sobre la integral (`0.5*x**4`), pero aqui me limite a reproducir el código original, corrigiendo los problemas formales sin entrar a cuestionar su validez matemática.